# How to group values of two arrays in a third array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have bellow this two arrays:

```
var t1 = ["18:00", "19:00", "20:00"]
var t2 = ["44:00", "23:00", "21:00"]
```

and I want to group their values in another array like this

```
var t3 = ["18:00 - 44:00", "19:00 - 23:00", "20:00 - 21:00"]
```

I tried some things with nested for loops and maps but I didn't even get close to what I expected.

Comment: `var t3 = t1.map((x, i) => x + ' - ' + t2[i]);` (using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

Comment: A single for loop t3[i]=t1[i]+" - "+t2[i] should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var t1 = ["18:00", "19:00", "20:00"]
var t2 = ["44:00", "23:00", "21:00"]
var t3 = t1.map((_, i) => `${t1[i]} - ${t2[i]}`);
console.log(t3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var t1 = ["18:00", "19:00", "20:00"]
var t2 = ["44:00", "23:00", "21:00"]
var t3 = []

for(var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++){
    t3.push(`${t1[i]} - ${t2[i]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t3 = t1.map((t, index) => `${t} - ${t2[index]}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var t1 = ["18:00", "19:00", "20:00"];
var t2 = ["44:00", "23:00", "21:00"];
let t3 = [];

for (let i=0; i<t1.length; i++) {
    t3.push(t1[i]+" - "+t2[i]);
}

console.log(t3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map **through the first array** and adding the value of the **second array**, by using the **index** value :

```
var t1 = ["18:00", "19:00", "20:00"]
var t2 = ["44:00", "23:00", "21:00"]

var t3 = t1.map((element, index) => {
  return element + ' - ' + t2[index]
})
```

The map method offers access to the index